# In how many ways can a teacher sit k students on n chairs so that no 2 students sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $n$ chairs in a row. In how many ways can a teacher sit k students on these chairs so that no $2$ students sit next to each other (and obviously no $2$ students sit on $1$ chair)?

I think that is not a typical stars and bars problem. It is not exactly $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ right?

Comment: Your question is mostly identical to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/how-many-ways-are-there-for-8-men-and-5-women-to-stand-in-a-line-so-that-no-two

Comment: No, it's not $n! (k+1)!$. What are your thoughts after reading the top answer to the question I linked? Did you find that answer helpful?

Comment: Yea i think so. I just made a little misunderstanding and then posted answer too quickly. The true answer regarding to linked topic should be n!(n+1 choose k) * k!.

Comment: [This exact question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334018/sitting-in-chairs-with-empty-space) has been answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a student at the right end or not.  If so, the rest of the students need an empty seat to their right, so attach a seat to each.  You have $k-1$ pairs of student/empty and (how many) empty seats left?  How many ways to arrange them.  If not, attach a seat again and ...